# Lost sessions after ISP moved my site to new server

Tags: php, cookies, session

I'm having some sessions problems after my ISP moved my site to a new server, supposedly setup the same. The problem appears to be browser-specific as well, which I don't quite understand.

First, my site uses sessions to login, this has been broken since they moved the site.

My ISP has set up [a test page](http://launchcomplex.com/loggedin_test1.php). When I hit this page in IE 6 (where it sets some session vars) and then hit the "header redirect" button, sessions seem to work fine. If I try it in Firefox/Opera, I get a new session id on the redirected page. My ISP reports sessions are working for IE as well, though I imagine they're using IE7 or perhaps even 8.

Everything was working fine on my site before my ISP moved it and while they've been very helpful in responding, they're at a loss as to why it's broken. A couple of other of my sites with them were broken along with the move, but they have been resolved by server tweaks...Does anyone have any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

You're redirecting from "launchcomplex.com" to "www.launchcomplex.com"

If you set [`session.cookie_domain`](http://www.php.net/session.cookie_domain) it should work - see [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://www.php.net/session_set_cookie_params)

> Cookie domain, for example 'www.php.net'. To make cookies visible on all subdomains then the domain must be prefixed with a dot like '.php.net'.

Answer (score 1):

When they moved servers, did they move to a clustered configuration?  Meaning when I hit your web page, am I always requesting content from the same physical server, or could be be any of a cluster of servers?

If the latter, that is your problem.  Sessions are by default file-based, and thus are not scalable to multiple servers.

One solution is to use session_set_save_handler() to write your own session manager.  Usually you would use a database to read/write session data using this method.